# script error at the bottom left corner when selenium IE webdriver drives the IE

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open a webpage using selenium ie webdriver. the page opens with a script error icon at the bottom left corner. When I manually go to the same page. there is no error.

Because of this script error the selenium is not able to move further. when I double click that a popup shows and selenium starts again.

Any ideas what is causing that and how to overcome this problem?

Error -document.getElementById(…) is null or not an object.

Comment: Please add more info and code you are using. Also, what is the error message displayed when you click the script error icon in the status bar?

Comment: I have included the error. The only thing I found was IE8 version. I ran the same thing on another computer whose ie8 version was different, the code worked just fine.